# Issues with repositioning the datagrid

Tags: powershell, datagridview

Im trying to move the datagridview to another Location in the form. I have tried multiple different methods but, the data grid remains anchored to the top left. Can anyone help?

Here is my code however it doesnt reflect all attempts.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
$DataGridView1.Left = 200
$DataGridView1.Right = 200
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$dataGridView1.Location = "75, 75"
$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 4
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "A"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "B"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "C"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "D"

$row1 = '1','2','3','4'

#$rows = @($row1)
#foreach ($row in $rows)
#{    
#$dataGridView.Rows.Add($row.name)}
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $DrawX = 150
 $DrawY = 150
 $DataGridView.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new($DrawX,$DrawY)
```

This will place the datagrid box anywhere on the form. Stumbled across this code snippet in my notes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).